# Personalize private key on Smart Card

Tags: smartcard, apdu

I have some issues regarding a `PUT DATA` command on private and public key containers.

According to my specification, these container don't accept `GENERATE ASYMMETRIC KEY PAIR` command but only `PUT DATA` through secure messaging.

```
00 DB 3FFF Lc [DATA]
```

Here is my data before applying secure messaging :

```
70 82 029F 
    BF9005 82 0299
        7F48 82 0294 
            92 81 81 00fd5ab35d5ce5cfc2b7e9549330f121079cc10135647e9093a713d1897b582b5629615e3f8d2523bef4f884ff2ea18342f81944322f7c2ed9f1648874578aea1c3b12700abe86283b4cd5727922c7d25a0a319829c051266c42039c4383d272ab7d3ffd2bdb0f620bc1e37c2c2c4b54ba3698c375b18f694b5b62e2cb458a981f
            93 81 81 00df8c67d5094e3a11c19fd67ca988e80d886f723f9af3db43f5e30f85eb1f405c266f3149824aec7c67172289c5996755ca06dee83a2285cf8621822afd03f88e0324b04d400ef73325291ef7665f1368b6d25ba85417e2b41a501113493b406569b7cf00bb3936cb0a3662e4592d94d811c26efe03cc35f0890077eca3ce2f57
            94 81 81 0090c88ab961c2b15c8269bdd151fe9703d81ddea623be610b02d7c24c81ad4b5b51e4f805215f867a782256859cfe1923f12047673d67d712cdeca0dff32494d3a3038200740b681d5b8849fa05c92b2fa07f7985e4a9a30ed9298c61d0ccf17abce7bdd3bcb93502ef54519752afc520967107c917006dab7d27c9747126d8ce
            95 81 81 00c2f9011df176fe1b48b36d1dd5454bf8f2be6972b082e23a6f12c6677a1fd141fe986b129749a4a7b918642989b64c30c6839342d7de46a3fcac3482ec38009077396a362a874e00ccd15ac63468f8cdc818809468e74a9d777415d6b364ca508514307e8697e109514e02ea6fb00d653cccf566e69d8a17af1d7b919953de5b
            96 81 81 0090c88ab961c2b15c8269bdd151fe9703d81ddea623be610b02d7c24c81ad4b5b51e4f805215f867a782256859cfe1923f12047673d67d712cdeca0dff32494d3a3038200740b681d5b8849fa05c92b2fa07f7985e4a9a30ed9298c61d0ccf17abce7bdd3bcb93502ef54519752afc520967107c917006dab7d27c9747126d8ce
```

I send this data per packet with the `10` CLA.
After applying secure messaging, my CLA is becoming: `1C` and `0C` for the last command.

Here are the APDUs before secure messaging but after chaining:

```
10DB3FFF6c7082029FBF90058202997F4882029492818100fd5ab35d5ce5cfc2b7e9549330f121079cc10135647e9093a713d1897b582b5629615e3f8d2523bef4f884ff2ea18342f81944322f7c2ed9f1648874578aea1c3b12700abe86283b4cd5727922c7d25a0a319829c051266c42
10DB3FFF6c039c4383d272ab7d3ffd2bdb0f620bc1e37c2c2c4b54ba3698c375b18f694b5b62e2cb458a981f93818100df8c67d5094e3a11c19fd67ca988e80d886f723f9af3db43f5e30f85eb1f405c266f3149824aec7c67172289c5996755ca06dee83a2285cf8621822afd03f88e03
10DB3FFF6c24b04d400ef73325291ef7665f1368b6d25ba85417e2b41a501113493b406569b7cf00bb3936cb0a3662e4592d94d811c26efe03cc35f0890077eca3ce2f579481810090c88ab961c2b15c8269bdd151fe9703d81ddea623be610b02d7c24c81ad4b5b51e4f805215f867a78
10DB3FFF6c2256859cfe1923f12047673d67d712cdeca0dff32494d3a3038200740b681d5b8849fa05c92b2fa07f7985e4a9a30ed9298c61d0ccf17abce7bdd3bcb93502ef54519752afc520967107c917006dab7d27c9747126d8ce95818100c2f9011df176fe1b48b36d1dd5454bf8f2
10DB3FFF6cbe6972b082e23a6f12c6677a1fd141fe986b129749a4a7b918642989b64c30c6839342d7de46a3fcac3482ec38009077396a362a874e00ccd15ac63468f8cdc818809468e74a9d777415d6b364ca508514307e8697e109514e02ea6fb00d653cccf566e69d8a17af1d7b9199
10DB3FFF6c53de5b9681810090c88ab961c2b15c8269bdd151fe9703d81ddea623be610b02d7c24c81ad4b5b51e4f805215f867a782256859cfe1923f12047673d67d712cdeca0dff32494d3a3038200740b681d5b8849fa05c92b2fa07f7985e4a9a30ed9298c61d0ccf17abce7bdd3bc
00DB3FFF1bb93502ef54519752afc520967107c917006dab7d27c9747126d8ce
```

Each time, the card gives me a status word: `6A80` which means *Incorrect data in command*.

I also tried with the RSA public key container, I read the public data :

```
70 82 011E 
    BFA005 82 0118 
        7F49 82 0113 
            80 01 1A 
            81 82 0100 D2E4E1BA0228DBB12F3274CB27E33492C3525B198D778D00F0404900B956C7B4013ECDE01FBDFAC68B037339F8847E9BDC69F1AD2B177C93621305D3660A8A4E2085F85E9B030DA6AC35342249ACBD18563F9B72E7955D02E94098E675623DC9E870E761D27ED2926538DF62F8722C97D9450DA8E05F168F9C42F1EE885C446B613BF549B962022DD6BD6C8FBCF4BD9D7000DC189495C768A88B40D090D1EF01065F815E8A9904620A7E5B44C917168C1C2B35E428CC0E39A22768F5C8BA65346AD35C03813F46C44B80830343F23DB471ACE99B6AE03987B822CB37ED541DB5B29239D31197170A7F9671C0F23DC8C1B4C655EF901BB91BEE716C4999919ADF
            82 04 00010001
            5F4C 00 
            5F20 00
```

Removed some stuff (like `5F20 tag, 80 tag`)

```
70 82 0115
    BFA005 82 010F
        7F49 82 010A 
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
            82 04 00010001
```

So the data are good, they came from the container itself.

Here my apdu before applying secure messaging :

```
10DB3FFF4070820115BFA00582010F7F4982010A81820100D2E4E1BA0228DBB12F3274CB27E33492C3525B198D778D00F0404900B956C7B4013ECDE01FBDFAC68B037339F8
10DB3FFF40847E9BDC69F1AD2B177C93621305D3660A8A4E2085F85E9B030DA6AC35342249ACBD18563F9B72E7955D02E94098E675623DC9E870E761D27ED2926538DF62F8
10DB3FFF40722C97D9450DA8E05F168F9C42F1EE885C446B613BF549B962022DD6BD6C8FBCF4BD9D7000DC189495C768A88B40D090D1EF01065F815E8A9904620A7E5B44C9
10DB3FFF4017168C1C2B35E428CC0E39A22768F5C8BA65346AD35C03813F46C44B80830343F23DB471ACE99B6AE03987B822CB37ED541DB5B29239D31197170A7F9671C0F2
00DB3FFF193DC8C1B4C655EF901BB91BEE716C4999919ADF820400010001
```

Same here, I got a `6A80`

Card ATR : `3B7F1800000031B8645023ECC173940180829000`

My application is working in production since 2 years. The core (transmission of APDU, secure messaging manager, etc) is working fine.

Here an extract of the spec : http://hpics.li/7eb3240 (can't put the picture on stack)

Someone have an idea about what is wrong in my APDU?

Comment: So we continue debugging. What transmission protocol are you using? What has changed? Card version? The CLA byte? The command chaining? The error doesn't mean anything without additional context, "incorrect data" just means that the command data is incorrect. That could be anything.

Comment: The BER encoding now seems valid, although `BF9005` indicates a pretty high tag number.

Comment: I edited with some informations.
BF9005 : 90 stand for private key, and 05 the id

Comment: Is that a french ID card? I'm still not sure what has changed on your side, just the RSA key or is there more? You don't need to send the modulus or public exponent as well? I presume these are just the CRT private key parameters?

Comment: This is a french Card. I try to inject a new private key and  then I will inject the corresponding public key. Nothing changed in my app, this is the first time I need to use putdata.
The main goal : I have a card that has encryption container, I need to clean them, so I want to put new keys and generate assym key pair is forbid on that container .
Thanks for your time btw

Comment: It may make more sense to inject the public key first so the private key can be verified. As said, I see 5 RSA/CRT parameters. You may need a modulus as well, I presume that would be tag `91`. I hope one of these possibilities fits. Unfortunately I don't have the French ID personalization specs ready.

Comment: I added an extract of the spec regarding the RSA object.
Each one have to be update separatly. The same issue occured when I try to  edit the public key.

Comment: So you tried tag `80` as well, right? Or is that already supposed to be on the card? Sheesh, I need to update my French.

Comment: Sorry for that, the tick mean : "optional" and the point on the last column mean "can be update", so the tag 80 can't be update.

Comment: Hmm, OK, and the card is OK with 2048 bit keys, right?